# I am unable to download elementary OS

Tags: software-installation, elementary-website

When I go to [elementary.io](http://elementary.io) and try to download the iso file the screen goes darker and nothing happens.

I have tried multiple computers and browsers.

[image]

EDIT: I am currently using Google Chrome ver. Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit) I am running OSX 10.11 (Developer Beta 2) 
On this machine I also tried using Safari 9.0 and Firefox 37.0.1 (Without any extensions/plugins)

I have tried on another machine running OSX Yosemite using Safari, Firefox, and Google Chrome (Without extensions/plugins).

Comment: With what browser? What version? On what operating system? Do you have any unusual configuration, e.g. ad blocker, cookie blocker, etc.?

Comment: @Ben could you list what all blockers/extensions you have? it looks like you have quite a few

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+N then browse there.

Comment: I did donate and I have tried using incognito mode. Thanks for the direct download links. They work.

Comment: This happens as soon as you enter the site or after clicking the Download button or when?

Comment: My guess would be that the adblocker filter rules dislike `id="download-modal"` here. As elementary has no ads on its site it's quite safe to disable your adblocker here... Edit: Re-read the question, if by "without plugins" you also mean "without addons" then my comment is wrong. Could someone else with OSX test the site?

Comment: Yes I mean without addons/extensions. And in incognito mode those shouldn't be active. Or in different browsers.

Comment: This happens immediately after I click the "Download Freya" button.

Comment: This is what you should be seeing: http://postimg.org/image/tcdu0dhjn/. My guess is that the pop over window is being hidden by some add-on/extension in your Browser. Have you tried with Midori?

Comment: To my knowledge, both AdBlock, AdBlock plus, and Ghostery do not block the modal window with all their available lists turned on.

Comment: I am flagging to close this question because it is about a transient error which has now been fixed, so it will not be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was a small issue with the modal, which has since [been fixed](https://github.com/elementary/mvp/pull/745) by the web team.